# send multiple dict in payload in a post requests fails

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to make a post request for [this api endpoint](https://ecomdash.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/56a62d3be7b19d09a48c9b72/operations/5790eb90ec719b267c471036?)
I am trying to update multiple product at once, my best try is :

```
payload = [{
    'Sku': '101',
    'Quantity': 122,
    'WarehouseId': 16
  },
  {
      'Sku': '102',
      'Quantity': 126,
      'WarehouseId': 15
   }
  ]

url = 'https://ecomdash.azure-api.net/api/inventory/updateQuantityOnHand'
try:
    res = requests.post(url, data = payload, headers=headers)
    print(res.status_code)
    print(res.content)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

It gives me this error: "too many values to unpack"
I think I have done something wrong in the payload. headers param is ok as for same value it works when I test from the " api documentation Try It" section. Even when I use this payload,

```
payload = {
    'Sku': '101',
    'Quantity': 122,
    'WarehouseId': 16
     }
```

The request returns a 200 but the update does not occur. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give us full error message

Comment: for the first payload (list of multiple dict), the error message is "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

for the second payload, the response is 200 but there is no update. 
I feel like I did something wrong in the payload. Thanks!

Comment: May be the endpoint accepts JSON-encoded data. If that's the case, try using `json=payload` instead of `data=payload`. Alternatively, add this to the headers: `Content-Type: application/json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint accepts data in body, not in data. The correct code is,

```
res = requests.post(url, json = payload, headers=headers)
```

Thanks @m01010011 for the hint. I got mixed up in the query parameter and request body. Really appreciate your help.